# Apache Automatic Virtual Host set up on OSX

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I am trying to have something like this:

`/Users/stu/Sites/Project1/site1_app/ –> site1.local
/Users/stu/Sites/AlphaProX/prox_app/ –> prox.local`

I have about 20 entries and I was curious to know if I can have this setup. I had asked the question at [Sever Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/534342/apache-automatic-virtual-host-set-up-on-osx) but apparently my question is for a developer type of configuration. Please provide a sample virtualhost entry.

Answer (score 1):

*Coolest Guy on the Planet* has an article on how to set up [Virtual Hosts on Os X 10.8 Mountain Lion](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/how-set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-108-mountain-lion) manually with Apache configuration files.

If you're more a GUI-type you can also try [MAMP PRO](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or the cheaper alternative: [Virtualhostx](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/) possibly [in combination](http://support.clickontyler.com/a/17/setup-virtualhostx-and-mamp/) with the free version of [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html).